# generate session key for facebook connect

Tags: java, facebook

i m developing a blackberry app in which i need to send a mssg to the wall of all my facebook friends, for this i need to have a session key. i have api key, secret key and obviously userid and password. how do i get the session key. i want to know about the api to do this.Any one please help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the examples that are posted for the Facebook API at http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/wiki/Examples